# Azure github deploy and Automatic Package Restore

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure, kudu

I am trying to deploy a project via project Kudu and Git hub on azure, without success.
This is the deploy log:

`Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Common.Logging, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Common.Logging.Core, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=af08829b84f0328e, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Ctl.Data, Version=1.0.5570.18090, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Ctl.Data.Excel, Version=1.0.5568.30276, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EPPlus, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Pechkin, Version=0.5.8.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Pechkin.Synchronized, Version=0.5.8.1, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\PdfExporter.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Pechkin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\PdfExporter.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Pechkin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(134,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(139,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelPackage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(170,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorksheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(181,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorksheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(208,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorksheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(227,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorksheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(284,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelWorksheet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(292,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelStyle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(313,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelVerticalAlignment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
Exporters\ExcelExporter.cs(327,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelHorizontalAlignment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting\XPTO.Infrastructure.Exporting.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
Request\Base\BaseRequest.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
UrbanAirSharpGateway.cs(10,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
UrbanAirSharpGateway.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
UrbanAirSharpGateway.cs(44,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
Request\Base\BaseRequest.cs(20,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ILog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\UrbanAirSharp\UrbanAirSharp.csproj]
  XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.DTO -> D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.DTO\bin\Release\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.DTO.dll
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(2,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(6,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(14,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<ConfigurationDocument>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(15,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<ConfigurationSection>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(16,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet<ConfigurationAttribute>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(18,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbModelBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
ConfigurationContext.cs(18,33): error CS0115: 'ConfigurationContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)': no suitable method found to override [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
Migrations\Configuration.cs(3,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
Migrations\Configuration.cs(5,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbMigrationsConfiguration<XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.ConfigurationContext>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
Migrations\Configuration.cs(12,33): error CS0115: 'Configuration.Seed(ConfigurationContext)': no suitable method found to override [D:\home\site\repository\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data\XPTO.Infrastructure.Configuration.Data.csproj]
  PayoneerApi -> D:\home\site\repository\PayoneerApi\bin\Release\PayoneerApi.dll
  TipAir.EntityFramework -> D:\home\site\repository\TipAir.EntityFramework\bin\Release\TipAir.EntityFramework.dll
  ExtendedServerAPI -> D:\home\site\repository\ExtendedServerAPI\bin\Release\ExtendedServerAPI.dll
  NexmoApi -> D:\home\site\repository\NexmoApiSM\bin\Release\NexmoApi.dll
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
AuthorizePayment\AuthorizePaymentRequest.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
AuthorizePayment\AuthorizePaymentResponseObject.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
AuthorizePayment\AuthorizePaymentResponseObject.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
Common\FullPaymentMethod.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
Common\PaymentMethodDetails.cs(19,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
PaymentDetails\PaymentDetailsResponseObject.cs(76,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
PaymentDetails\PaymentDetailsResponseObject.cs(76,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PropertyName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\home\site\repository\ZooZPaymentAPI\ZooZPaymentAPI.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\TipAir.AdminSite\TipAir.AdminSite.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="D:\local\Temp\8d3cba35e7ed9a5";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\57.50815.2378\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"`

I removed some of the errors, was only reference problems, like the ones on the example.

Thanks, everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Jambor guidance, I found the problem.
Some of my Nuget references was pointing to a invalid folder.
I edited all the .csproj files, and now the deploy is working.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems a lot of assemblies are missing. For this type issue, I would suggest you set copy local as true via following steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, click the Show All Files button to display the References node.
2. Open the References node for the project.
   Right-click all reference in the References list, and click Properties.
3. Select Copy Local value to True.

Comment: I made it to all dlls I get from NuGet. Having the same error. Checked my depoyment folder via kudu and all packages is there. Do I need to copy the .NET Framework dlls too (System, System.Web, etc)?

Comment: New info. Tried to compile a project, directly via kudu console. But, it are pointing to a wrong package folder. Do you know how I change the package folder info? Thanks